# Create nxn matrix from pyspark datafame

Tags: pyspark

I am quite new to pyspark. I have 10k text data set. I create a Jaccard distance using Minhash lsh . 
the output i got like for example

```
col1 col2 dist
A   B       0.77
B   C       0.56
C   A       0.88
```

I want to convert this to NxN matrix format.

```
    A        B      C
A   0       0.77    0.88

B   0.77     0      0.56

C   0.88    0.56    0
```

Is there any way to create this using pyspark.
I appreciate the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It can done using the code below. However, it will be very computationally intensive because of the `groupBy`, `pivots`, `union` and then again `groupBy`. The two **groupBy pivots** are there because there are two combinations in your data `A-B` and `B-A`.

```
df1=df.groupBy("col1").pivot("col2").agg(F.first("dist")).orderBy("col1")
df2=df.groupBy(F.col("col2").alias("col1")).pivot("col1").agg(F.first("dist")).orderBy("col1")
df3=df1.union(df2)
df3.groupBy("col1")\
.agg(*(F.first(x,True).alias(x) for x in df3.columns if x != 'col1'))\
.fillna(0)\
.orderBy("col1")\
.show()

+----+----+----+----+
|col1|   A|   B|   C|
+----+----+----+----+
|   A| 0.0|0.77|0.88|
|   B|0.77| 0.0|0.56|
|   C|0.88|0.56| 0.0|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a sample example of 3 values(A,B,C) when i have more values how to do this, in the last section  df3 where .agg is happening adding value wise.

Comment: you could use this: .agg(*(F.first(x,True).alias(x) for x in df3.columns if x != 'col1')). i have updated solution